# Custom template for one specific post in a custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a little web app, that I want to run within a page in a custom post type on my WordPress site.
So I thought to just create a new template to put the specific code for this app there and assign this template to the custom post types page.

Sadly Wordpress is not showing me the template in my cpt.

The template file is called fretfind.php and the first lines contain:

```
/*  
Template Name: Fretfind 
Template Post Type: guitar
*/
```

'guitar' is the cpt slug.

Has anyone an idea why it doesn't show me the selecting option for this template. Are there any extra steps for Custom Post Type Templates?

Or is there generally another good practice to have just on one specific wordpress page custom php code? Something like a template for post ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this was a page, you could have used a template file called `page-{slug}.php`, where {slug} is the slug of the specific page (see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy).

But since we're talking about CPT there is unfortunately only `single-{$posttype}.php` and no `single-{$posttype}-{$slug}.php` (see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/#custom-post-type-templates)

However, you can add support for such template files for CPT by adding this code to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function( $template ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type === 'guitar' ) {
        $locate_template = locate_template( "single-guitar-{$post->post_name}.php" );
        if ( ! empty( $locate_template ) ) {
            $template = $locate_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
} );
```

And then use the template file `single-guitar-myspesificguitarslug.php` (where *myspesificguitarslug* is the slug of the CPT page where you want this template to apply)

Comment: Looks promising, but is somehow not working. I set the URL Slug to 'fretfind' and created 'single-guitar-fretfind.php' but I keep ending up at singular.php

Comment: Did you add the code to functions.php? Can you share a link?

Comment: Oh god... Your question for a link solved the problem. I normally work just on my local host for this project, but somehow I was the whole time trying to see the changes on the online version, but without uploading it because I thought I'm in the local environment. Anyway, now your code is working perfectly well, and I just need to handle the feeling of embarrassment for being that blind :D

Comment: Filter isn't needed anymore. You only need a new template file as described in the answer.